# Database entries added in background task don't show up on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, background-task

I have a background task in my django application, which enters all the rows from a csv into one of the tables in my database. I pass the csv via the admin site, that creates a background task, that I can run with `python manage.py process_tasks`. This all works locally, but on my heroku app, for some reason it doesn't.

I thought maybe inputting data is impossible from the heroku console, but if I run `python manage.py shell` on the heroku console, I can input data just fine.

This is the code that inputs the data into the database:

```py
from background_task import background

...

@background(schedule=5)
def save_course_from_df(df):
    df = pandas.read_json(df)
    db = 0
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        print("%s percent done!" % str(db / df.shape[0]))
        db += 1
        values = dict(row)
        values = {key: values[key] for key in values.keys()
                  if type(values[key]) != float or not math.isnan(values[key])}
        try:
            Course.objects.update_or_create(
                url=row['url'],
                defaults=values
            )
        except IntegrityError:
            pass
    print('done!')
```

I run this by opening the heroku console and running 'python manage.py process_tasks'. I get the print messages, and no error is being thrown. Still, my database doesn't change.

I expected that after the task runs I would have a full table. Instead, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was with my migrations. For some reason the database on the heroku app had a not null constraint for a column whose model had the null=True argument.